# Background normal and background active in css

Tags: css, html

I have the following code in CSS:

```
#nav li a:active{
 background-color:brown;
}

#nav li a.index{background:purple;}
#nav li a.advertiser{background:red;}
#nav li a.publisher{background:green;}
#nav li a.new{background:blue;}
#nav li a.status{background:orange;}

#nav li a:hover {
 border-bottom:5px solid brown;
}
```

and HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
 <li><a class="index"....
 <li><a class="advertiser"...
 <li><a class="publisher"...
 <li><a class="new"....
 <li><a class="status".....
</ul>
```

The thing is that when i click on it, it transforms to brown but it doesn't stay brown.
Where am i mistaking can't realize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:active`  will give the highlights when the button or text is pressed, you need to code jquery to achieve this. Try this example:

```
<ul>    
<li><a class="black classname" id="click">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="black" id="click">about</a></li>
<li><a class="black" id="click">services</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.black{color:black}
.classname{color:red}
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a#click").click(function(){
        $("a").removeClass('classname')
        $(this).addClass('classname')
    });

});
```

Demo  http://jsfiddle.net/XFYjz/

Comment: Your Jquery selectors aren't properly scoped; this code may break on a full page.

Answer (score 2):

the :active state will only be active when the user clicks on it; anchor or buttons' active states don't persists after the click is finished.

If you want to keep the anchor to brown after a click, you can use jquery to push a specific class when the user clicks on an anchor:

```
$('#nav a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //?

    $('#nav a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

Comment: Is it possible with javascript? Jquery it's a bit problematic for me.

Comment: Everything in Jquery is possible in javascript. Unfortunately, I don't have the time to write this in pure javascript. Sorry.